# Receiving "TypeError: this.cart.cases.get is not a function" even though function exists

Tags: dictionary, typescript, typeerror

When trying to do a key/value lookup on a Map in my Typescript controller, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: this.cart.cases.get is not a function

However, "get" is definitely defined for a Typescript Map. The calling controller looks like this:

```
export class CaseController{
    case: Case;
    cart: IShoppingCart;
    constructor(
        private $location: ng.ILocationService,
        private $mdDialog: ng.material.IDialogService,
        private $scope: any,
        private CaseService : CaseService,
        private shoppingCartService : ShoppingCartService
    ){
        "ngInject";
        var self = this;
        this.cartJSON = "";
        this.case = self.CaseService.getCase()
        this.cart = shoppingCartService.getCart();

    }

    public addDocument(doc:Document, caseForDoc:Case) {
      var myCase:Case = this.cart.cases.get(caseForDoc.caseId);//Error here
      if(!myCase){
        myCase = new Case(
            caseForDoc.id, 
            caseForDoc.caseNumber,
            caseForDoc.caseStyle, 
            caseForDoc.baseType,
            caseForDoc.status, 
            caseForDoc.fileDate,
            caseForDoc.caseId, 
            caseForDoc.location);
      }
      myCase.documents[doc.id.toString()] = doc;
      this.cart.cases.set(myCase.caseId, myCase);
      this.cartJSON = JSON.stringify(this.cart);
      this.shoppingCartService.updateCart(this.cart);    
    }
}
```

"cases" is a map, which is defined in IShoppingCart, which lookslike this:

```
export class ShoppingCart implements IShoppingCart {
    public cases: Map<number, Case>; //Mapped to caseid
     constructor(
        public id: number,
        public userIdentifier: string,
        public emailAddress: string,
        public convenienceFee: number,
        public orderTotal: number,
    ) {
        this.cases = new Map<number,Case>();
    }
```

All the code compiles fine. Any ideas?

EDIT: The addDocuments gets called in a view, in the portion shown below:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="(docID, doc) in vm.case.documents" layout="column" 
class="table-card" style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; border-top:1px solid #ddd; border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">
        <md-card-content>
            <div layout="row">
                <div flex-sm="100" flex-md="50" flex-lg="33" flex-gt-lg="33">
                    <tt-label-container>
                        <md-button class="md-primary md-hue-1" ng-click="vm.previewDoc($event)">
                             {{doc.documentName}}
                        </md-button>

                    </tt-label-container>
                </div>
                <div flex-sm="100" flex-md="50" flex-lg="33" flex-gt-lg="33">
                    <tt-label-container>
                        <div>{{doc.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</div>
                    </tt-label-container>
                </div>
                <div flex-sm="100" flex-md="50" flex-lg="33" flex-gt-lg="33">
                    <tt-label-container>
                        <div>{{doc.numberOfPages}}</div>
                    </tt-label-container>
                </div>
                <div flex-sm="100" flex-md="50" flex-lg="33" flex-gt-lg="33">
                    <tt-label-container>
                        <div>{{doc.price | currency: '$'}}</div>
                    </tt-label-container>
                </div>
                <div flex-sm="100" flex-md="50" flex-lg="33" flex-gt-lg="33">
                    <tt-label-container>
                        <div>
                            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click='vm.addDocument(doc, vm.case)'>
                                <span>{{add.selected ? 'Remove' : 'Add'}}</span>
                            </md-button>
                        </div>
                    </tt-label-container>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
```

Comment: Who's calling `addDocument` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this to check if your *cases* property is really a **Map**

```
this.cart = shoppingCartService.getCart();
console.log(this.cart.cases instanceof Map);
```

If the log is "false" you have to check how *shoppingCartService.getCart()* is getting the cart. I cannot assume the implementation of this method but I've got the feeling you get the cart through the network and deserialize it. Ensure at runtime if the returned object and belonged properties are really the ones that you are expecting for (even if you explicitly type the result variable).

Actually you can also check

```
this.cart = shoppingCartService.getCart();    
console.log(this.cart instanceof IShoppingCart);
```

You could be surprise of the result :)

Comment: The console.log() suggestion was the exact key to finding the problem. In the getCases() method, the ShoppingCart was deserialized from a cookie (ng-cookies) and read into the this.cart. The problem was that when the ShoppingCart object was put into the cookie in the first place, the Map was serialized to JSON as a simple associative array, without any of the Map class's get/put methods. So at runtime, I wasn't dealing with a Map at all!